# Keep order of json in JSONField in DB

Tags: python, json

I have model which has JSONField.

```
class UserData(models.Model):
    detail = JSONField()
```

then I input the data like this.

```
json = {
     "name":"melody",
     "status":"good",
     "method":'hard'
}

u = Userdata(detail=json)
u.save()
```

However the order of items are not kept. I want to keep the order `name`, `status`,`method`

Is there any way to keep the order of json items??

```
$python -V
Python 3.7.9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to a string or into an array with elements with "field" and "value" keys (see example below). That's the only way to keep the order. JSON is not designed to have a fixed order of key/value pairs.

```
[
   {field:"name",value:"melody"},
   {field:"status",value:"good"},
   {field:"method",value:'hard'}
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Array order is kept.